# Can I call a ClassB method from the delegate object?

Tags: objective-c, function, call

How can I call an Objective-C method from another class?

For instance in xCode I have two scripts: the delegate and another one. How might I call someFunction on script2 from the delegate?

Comment: Did you try #import "classTwo" ?

Comment: Yes and it doesn't really work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "script" you mean class, you would need to link both classes.

if objectA is delegate of objectB, when objectB call a method from the delegate protocol:

```
if ([self.delegate resposndsToSelector:@selector(classBdidSomething:)]) {
    [self.delegate performSelector:@selector(classBdidSomething:) withObject:self];
}
```

On the implementation of ClassA:

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Delegate methods
- (void)classBdidSomething:(ClassB *)objectB {
    [objectB methodToBeCalled];
}
```

If you get an error/warning (like warning: no '-methodToBeCalled' method found) when building on the line:

```
[objectB methodToBeCalled];
```

It means that you have to import ClassB to into your ClassA, by doing:

```
#import "ClassB.h"
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant could I call something on ClassB from the delegate? SOrry to be confusing.

Comment: have you seen my answer. I call [objectB methodToBeCalled]; from ClassA, on the delegate method.